libmariadb.dll - How to change default connection timeout
I use libmariadb.dll (native MariaDB connector/c) to connect to my MariaDB database.
I would like to update the default timeout when I try to connect to a MariaDB server and that this server is not available.
What function calls should I apply in the application code to make this timeout have an effect and how do I detect when a timeout has occurred.

Using the MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT as the option for the connection:
unsigned int timeout= 5;
mysql_optionsv(mysql, MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, (void *)&timeout);  

ref: Documentation Manual
